# whiteSpace in the xml line I'm trying to retrieve with AS3 code

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I've got this AS3 code :

```
var tomorrowWeather = xml.weatherdata.forecast.tabular.windSpeed name.@mps;
```

I'm trying to reach the "mps" element in an xml file online :

```
<weatherdata>
<forecast>
<tabular>
<time period="1" to="2017-04-04T12:00:00" from="2017-04-04T09:00:00">
<windDirection name="West" code="W" deg="278.2"/>
<windSpeed name="Light air" mps="1.0"/>
</time>
```

Problem : `windSpeed name` got a space so my AS3 code is throwing an syntax error(1086)

How can I manage this space between "windSpeed" and "name" in order to make my variable `tomorrowWeather = mps` ?

Comment: I don't think that's your problem.  `name` is a property/attribute of the windspeed node, there is supposed to be a space there.   you should be doing `...windSpeed.@mps`

Comment: xml.weatherdata.forecast.tabular.windSpeed.@mps

Comment: You're right ! But it seems that I absolutely need to mention the time period in order to display "mps". As the time period is always updating, any idea how can I do ?

Comment: @Steph Not sure I understand what you want to do. Node "windSpeed" is a child node of "time". You can bypass the node tree by E4X descendatns accessor: **xml..windSpeed.@mps** (xml..windSpeed means "all the descendants of xml node by the name of windSpeed"), but if there other windSpeed nodes somewhere on this XML they will get mixed in.